# easier way to subview a UIImagePickerController? mines not working

Tags: ios, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller

When I run my code and launch the camera with the code below I get my custom overlayView along with the default camera buttons. The only problem is, now, I get a blank black box where my UIImagePicker once was. I am simply trying to create a camera using the default UIImagePicker controls and buttons and then add my own IBOutlet UILabel over top of the default imagePickerController so that my label is displayed along with all the default camera controls. I'm having a terrible time accomplishing this though. cheers!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (self.image == nil &&  [self.videoFilePath length] == 0) {
        self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        self.imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 10;

        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        }
        self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:self.imagePicker.sourceType];

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OverlayView" owner:self options:nil];
        self.overlayView.frame = self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView.frame;
        self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView;
        self.overlayView = nil;
    }
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use my code. It worked fine. May be you achieve what you want. I created a controller, and used it's view to set `cameraOverlayView` property. I didn't use nib files, I created everything programmatically.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"86-camera"];

self.cameraOverlayViewController = [[CameraOverlayViewController alloc] init];
self.cameraOverlayViewController.picker = picker;

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
    picker.cameraOverlayView = self.cameraOverlayViewController.view;
    picker.delegate = self.cameraOverlayViewController;

}
else if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]) {
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
}
```

This is a code for custom `CameraOverlayViewController`:
Interface file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CameraOverlayViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImagePickerController *picker;

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
#import "CameraOverlayViewController.h"
#import "BButton.h"
#import "AnalyseViewController.h"
#import "Tree.h"

@interface CameraOverlayViewController ()
{
}
@end

@implementation CameraOverlayViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.view.opaque = NO;

    }
    return self;
}


- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    UIView *bottomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bottom - 150, 320, 150)];
    bottomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    BButton *button = [[BButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 25, 220, 50) type:BButtonTypePrimary];
    [button setTitle:@"Сфотографировать" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [bottomView addSubview:button];
    [self.view addSubview:bottomView];

    UIView *topView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 70)];
    topView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 310, 60)];
    infoLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    infoLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:18];
    infoLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    infoLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    infoLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    infoLabel.text = @"Поместите лист дерева внутри рамки, чтобы\nсфотографировать его.";
    [topView addSubview:infoLabel];

    [self.view addSubview:topView];

    UIView *bordersView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, topView.bottom + 10, 300, 300)];
    bordersView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    bordersView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    bordersView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    bordersView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [self.view addSubview:bordersView];
}


#pragma mark - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    AnalyseViewController *analyseViewController = [[AnalyseViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    analyseViewController.baseImage = image;
    analyseViewController.treesArray = [Tree retrieveAllTrees];

    UINavigationController *analyseNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:analyseViewController];

    [AppDel.tabBarController presentViewController:analyseNavController animated:YES completion:nil];
}


#pragma mark - Other methods

- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self.picker takePicture];
}

@end
```

Delete unneeded classes like BButton yourself.

Comment: I appreciate it! I'm too new to all of this to be able to really understand all of that but I'll try to fish through it and get what I can from it! thx

Comment: I changed a few lines of my code to be this instead `[self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
            }
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OverlayView" owner:self options:nil];
    self.overlayView.frame = self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView.frame;
    self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView;`and now I get the labels and the camera all on the same screen but the labels that I created are center aligned with the left edge of the frame which cuts half of them off. The default camera buttons are all aligned properly however. I don't get it

Comment: All my labels and everything are aligned to Superview also, so I really don't understand what's going on

Comment: If you want to use nib files so much, then try to create UIViewController with a xib and use it's view as a cameraOverlayView.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it with this. I did some research on CGPoints & CGRect and come up with this solution. Not sure if it is the most elegant solution but it works and seems to make pretty good sense.         - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

```
    if (self.image == nil &&  [self.videoFilePath length] == 0) {
        self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        self.imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 10;

        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        }
        self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:self.imagePicker.sourceType];
        [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
            }
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OverlayView" owner:self options:nil];
    self.overlayView.frame = CGRectMake(160,0,0,0);
    self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView;

}
```